# Bootstrap - Reducing spacing between form-controls like textbox and label

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing the a .NET(C#) MVC web-application.
I have the following bootstrap drop-down menu.

I'm trying to achieve the following two things :

- 1) **I'm trying to reduce the spacing between a label and it's respective text-box**. I tried using "col-xs-1 col-form-label" instead of "col-xs-2 col-form-label" but then the textbox overlapped the label.
- 2) I want to reduce the height of the textbox.

How can I achieve these?

here's my cshtml code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar" />

        <div class="input-group-btn">

            <div class="btn-group" role="group">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ReloadData()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" onclick="ReloadData()"></span></button>

                <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Click To Expand"></button>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="font-family:Calibri;font:94% 'v', sans-sarif;background-color:#FAFAFA">
                            <br />

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="RequestNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Request No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtChopRequestNo" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ReloadData()" />
                                </div>

                                <label for="ReferenceNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Reference No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtReferenceNo" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ReloadData()" />
                                </div>

                                <label for="RequestNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Request No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtCreatedBy" />
                                    @*@Html.TextBox("name",null, new { id = "txtCreatedBy", style = "width:156px;" })*@                             
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="RequestNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Request No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtChopper" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ReloadData()" />
                                </div>

                                <label for="RequestNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Request No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtManager" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ReloadData()" />
                                </div>

                                <label for="RequestNo" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Request No.</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtLeagalApprover" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ReloadData()" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           //and so on

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" id="clearAll" style="background-color:#cc0000" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Clear All Search Parameters">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS code :

```
.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
}
.input-group-btn .btn-group {
    display: flex !important;
}
.btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.form-group .form-control:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #adv-search {
        width: 1110px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
        position: static !important;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 1110px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to reduce the spacing between a label and it's respective text-box.

Give your texboxes a css class (pull-left or whatever you want to call it) and then use css to pull the textboxes to the left.

.pull-left {
    margin-left: -20px; /* Try with different values until you are happy */
}

> I want to reduce the height of the textbox.

Try using `padding` and `line-height` and play with the numbers until you are happy with the height:

```
input[type="text"]{ padding: 20px 10px; line-height: 28px; }
```

The above will apply 20px to top and bottom and 10px to left and right. Here are some other ways:

```
padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
```

Finally make sure these margins play well when you are changing the size of the screen. If it looks good on big screen, it may not look good on smaller screens so choose something which will look good across all screens.

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi.

Comment: I was also able to solve my send requirement by directly using the 'height' property. It works well irrespective of any screen sizes.

Comment: And the spacing how did you do that?

Comment: Sorry a typo in my part. " I was also able to solve my SECOND requirement by directly using the 'height' property "

Comment: For spacing I implemented your suggestion (margin-left) [also had to use     !important ]

Comment: You can also post your own answer with how you did it and if it's helpful to others, you will get votes.